# Golang mongodb Aggregation too many values in primitive.E

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm trying to do a mongo aggregation. 
I made this query in MongoDB :

```
db.mongo.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {"host":"$host"}, "last_exec": {$last: "$time"}, "status": {$last: "$status"}}}]);
```

I use package : go.mongodb.org 
I want to implement it in my code in Golang with :

```
groupStage := bson.D{{"$group", bson.D{{"_id", bson.D {{"host", "$host"}}, "last_exec", bson.D{{"$last", "$time"}}, "status", bson.D{{"$last", "$status"}}}}}}
cursor, err = collection.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{groupStage})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to Aggregate: ", err)
}
if err = cursor.All(ctx, &metas); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("cursor.All() error:", err)
}
```

When I run my program it returns the following error:

```
too many values in primitive.E{...}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the problem ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code for the `groupStage` (it worked for me):

```
groupStage := bson.D{{"$group", bson.D{{"_id", bson.D{{"host", "$host"}}}, {"last_exec", bson.D{{"$last","$time"}}}}}}
```